# Can I link to a links list/app item and open the associated URL directly?

Tags: sharepoint-online, hyperlink, links-list

This question was also asked in 2015 by DeNaeL:
[Can I link to a links list/app list item and open the URL directly?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/159982/can-i-link-to-a-links-list-app-list-item-and-open-the-url-directly)
Tried the suggested answer by John-M but does not seem to work.

Using Sharepoint Online:
I would like to manage links in a central location (SP links list) and reference these links in a text webpart on a (modern) page.

I have put all of the links into a links list/app. I then linked to the links list item, just like a document. Unfortunately, this opens up the links item and then the URL must be clicked to get to the target.

Can I link to a links list/app item and open the associated URL directly?

Answer (score 0):

Use the modern [List](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-list-web-part-ef0a1b80-f8b3-443d-b04a-1e76c70b5537) webpart to display your links list.  If you only want to display a subset of those links you can specify a particular filtered View of that list.  With modern lists, you can even use [JSON custom formatting](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://support.office.com/en-us/article/formatting-list-views-f737fb8b-afb7-45b9-b9b5-4505d4427dd1&ved=2ahUKEwjW9Ybnts7nAhWZUs0KHUNyA1cQFjABegQIDRAG&usg=AOvVaw0zj3kHaMA8v1ylQiYjSYY8) to do specialized displays of that list.

Comment: Thank you willman unfortunately this is not exactly what I am looking for. I am aware of the List webpart. What I am looking for is : I want to use a link in the link list in the text (webpart) of a modern web page.

Comment: You can't put webparts inside other webparts. If you want a link inside the Text webpart, you will have to manually put the URL in there.

Comment: If you create a custom JSON formatted view, you can add other custom text and markup to the view in addition to the link items in that view.  Then you can use the List webpart to display this custom view on a modern page.  The rich text will only be able to be changed by editing the custom JSON formatter.